# Data won't transfer between elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a text area with the id of textBox, and I have a paragraph with the id of pwbox. Like so

```
<p id="pwbox"></p>
<textarea align="center" style="visibility:hidden;" id="textBox" autofocus></textarea>
```

I'm trying to hide the visible one and transfer the content of it to the hidden one. Then delete the content of the one that I'm hiding by calling hideP() like so:

```
<script>

var pHidden="no";

function hideP()
{
    if (pHidden=="no"){

        document.getElementById("textBox").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pwbox").innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
        document.getElementById("pwbox").innerHTML = " ";
        document.getElementById("pwbox").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("textBox").style.visibility = "visible";
        pHidden = "yes";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("pwbox").innerHTML = document.getElementById("textBox").innerHTML += "|";
        document.getElementById("textBox").innerHTML = " ";
        document.getElementById("pwbox").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("textBox").style.visibility = "hidden";
        pHidden = "no";
    };

};

</script>
```

It will switch the visibility but it won't transfer the content correctly, anyone know where I messed up at?

I call the function with something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void" onclick="hideP()">Swap</a>
```

also the `slice` and `+="|"` is a mock cursor and is supposed to be there.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: One thing `var pHidden=="no";` should be `var pHidden="no";`

Comment: Use `.value` to get the contents of a `textarea`.

Comment: Don't use strings for boolean values, use booleans.

Comment: `if (pHidden="no")` should be `if (pHidden=="no")

Comment: Use booleans: `var pHidden = false;` and `if (!pHidden)`

Comment: @Barmar they are, that was a typo, sorry

Comment: @Barmar, I can't use booleans, I intend to have other functions for other things later on. I didn't know to use . value for a textarea though, that's probably my issue.

Comment: @Barmar The .value advice fixed my program, if you want to answer it I'll give you the answer and an upvote. Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Davie Can't post answers to closed questions.